# Which is an acceptable approach for testing commands in Laravel 5.2 with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, tdd, laravel-5

I'm trying to write test cases for *Commands* in PHPUnit, without much success.

At this point I've tried many things, being probably [this post](https://laravelista.com/testing-laravel-commands) the closest approach I found for my purpose. Still, I'm struggling a lot to get this working.

Follows an example output for you:

```
alariva@trinsic ~/timegrid.io/app $ phpunit --filter=SendBusinessReportTest
PHP Warning:  The use statement with non-compound name 'Artisan' has no effect in /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/tests/unit/Console/Commands/SendBusinessReportTest.php on line 4
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:138
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:657
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuite() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Configuration.php:789
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Configuration.php:873
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:409
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:335
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:76
PHPUnit 4.8.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method App\Console\Kernel::resolve() in /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 217
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:440
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:747
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:747
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:724
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:612
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:768
PHP  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:909
PHP  12. SendBusinessReportTest->it_tests_command() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:909
PHP  13. Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::resolve() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/tests/unit/Console/Commands/SendBusinessReportTest.php:14
PHP  14. Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic() /home/alariva/timegrid.io/app/tests/unit/Console/Commands/SendBusinessReportTest.php:14

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Call to undefined method App\Console\Kernel::resolve()
```

You can find [my current attempt here](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/blob/enhance/artisan-command-tests/tests/unit/Console/Commands/SendBusinessReportTest.php), (broken tests), but maybe you can hint me something I'm missing :)

Just for reference, how I'm doing right now but does not seem to cover the code: [Coverage Report](https://codeclimate.com/github/timegridio/timegrid/coverage/576ef819af9c910001006757) and [Test Case](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid/blob/master/tests/acceptance/commands/SendBusinessReportTest.php)

> Side Note: You may ask why PHPUnit and not another testing framework. So far I'm generating my **test coverage with PHPUnit** and I'd like to stick to it until I feel the actual need to switch.  However, all suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to an acceptable approach as follows:

```
<?php

use App\Console\Commands\SendBusinessReport;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application as ConsoleApplication;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;
use Timegridio\Concierge\Models\Appointment;

class SendBusinessReportTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;
    use CreateBusiness, CreateUser, CreateContact, CreateAppointment, CreateService, CreateVacancy;

    /** @test */
    public function it_reports_to_all_businesses()
    {
        $this->arrangeFixture();

        // BEGIN Actual solution code
        $application = new ConsoleApplication();

        $testedCommand = $this->app->make(SendBusinessReport::class);
        $testedCommand->setLaravel(app());
        $application->add($testedCommand);

        $command = $application->find('business:report');

        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);

        $commandTester->execute([
            'command' => $command->getName(),
        ]);
        // END Actual solution code

        $this->assertRegExp('/Scanning all businesses../', $commandTester->getDisplay());
    }

    /**
     * Arrange Fixture.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function arrangeFixture()
    {
        $this->owner = $this->createUser();
        $this->issuer = $this->createUser();

        $this->business = $this->createBusiness();
        $this->business->owners()->save($this->owner);

        $this->contact = $this->createContact();
        $this->contact->user()->associate($this->issuer);

        $this->service = $this->makeService();
        $this->business->services()->save($this->service);

        $this->vacancy = $this->makeVacancy();
        $this->vacancy->service()->associate($this->service);

        $this->business->vacancies()->save($this->vacancy);

        $appointment = $this->makeAppointment($this->business, $this->issuer, $this->contact, [
            'status' => Appointment::STATUS_CONFIRMED,
            ]);
    }
}


alariva@trinsic ~/timegrid.io/app $ phpunit --filter=it_reports_to_all_businesses
PHPUnit 5.4.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 813 ms, Memory: 30.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

[Reference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-do-you-test-your-commands-phpunit)

Answer (score 0):

In above case, you should remove `use Artisan;` because you don't use any namespace for your test

Comment: Thanks Marcin, however it seemed to be a bit more than we expected. I posted as reference the solution I reached so far.