# Testing Laravel (5.1) console commands with phpunit

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

What is the best way to test Laravel console commands?

Here is an example of a command I'm running. It takes in a value in the constructor and in the handle method.

```
class DoSomething extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'app:do-something';
    protected $description = 'Does something';

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function handle(B $b)
    {
        ...    
    }
}
```

In my test class, I can mock both A and B, but I can't figure out how to pass $a in.

```
$this->artisan('app:do-something', [$b]);
```

Is it possible? Or am I going about this all wrong? Should I pass everything in thought the handle() method?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to be able to mock A $a in this instance? Not just pass through the actual object?

Comment: In this case, it was my logger, so I didn't want to pass in the real instance.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to change around how you call the command in testing, but it is possible to mock an object passed through.

If the class used by Artisan is dependency-injected like this:

```
public function __construct(ActualObject $mocked_A)
{
    //
}
```

Then write up the test case like this:

```
$mocked_A = Mockery::mock('ActualObject');
$this->app->instance('ActualObject', $mocked_A);

$kernel = $this->app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
$status = $kernel->handle(
    $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput([
        'command' => 'app:do-something',
    ]),
    $output = new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput
);
$console_output = $output->fetch();
```

The `$this->app->instance('ActualObject', $mocked_A);` line is where you are able to call upon and use the mocked version of your class, or object, instead of the actual.

This will work in Laravel or Lumen.